# How to add a new line after every integer

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to figure out a way to make a new variable from another to output to a GUI. When I try to just display the variable through a lable it loses its line breaks.

I managed to figure out a solution when working with text but when it comes to numbers it does not work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$ActiveUnits = @(Get-MsolAccountSku | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ActiveUnits)

$ActiveUnitsFix = "`n"

foreach ($Unit in $ActiveUnits) {
    $ActiveUnitsFix += @($Unit + "`n")
}
```

The output that I am getting is this:

```
31425220100002521100001000000100000002137328420
```

When it should be something like this:

```
3
14
25
220
10000
25
21
10000
1000000
10000000
213
7
3
28
4
20
```

Comment: Instead of "`n" use [environment]::NewLine

Comment: @f6a4 Thanks for the response however I tried replacing the "`n" with [environment]::NewLine and I am still getting the same results

Comment: `$ActiveUnits = Get-MsolAccountSku | select ActiveUnits | format-table -HideTableHeaders` For me this works perfectly

Comment: `$ActiveUnits | Out-String`

Comment: what do you see if you leave off the `-ExpandProperty`? that SHOULD give you an array of digits OR `[int]` ... which otta NOT show as a single line of digits..

Comment: `@(Get-MsolAccountSku).ActiveUnits` should work, just tested

Comment: @robdy That does not work in PowerShell v2 b/c it relies on a feature that was introduced with v3 (member enumeration).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers correct, good observation. Didn't look at tags properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-join` parameter for adding the new line if you receive an int array from `(Get-MsolAccountSku).ActiveUnits`.

```
[System.Int32[]]$ActiveUnits  = (Get-MsolAccountSku).ActiveUnits
[System.String]$ActiveUnitsFix = $ActiveUnits -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
$ActiveUnitsFix
```